# ¿Cómo crear un mapa de imagen adaptativo?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, css, css3

¿Es posible crear un mapa de imagen (usando [`<map>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map) y [`<area>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area)) para hacer que ciertas areas de una imagen se conviertan en *hotspots* Y que la imagen (y el mapa) respondan bien a los cambios de tamaño y se adapten a la pantalla?

Por ejemplo, en este mapa de imagen se puede hacer click tanto en el círculo como el cuadrado:

```html
<map name="mapa">
  <area shape="circle" coords="125,125,50" href="javascript:alert('Círculo')" />
  <area shape="rectangle" coords="325,75,425,175" href="javascript:alert('Cuadrado')" />
</map>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvHyu.png" usemap="#mapa" />
```

Ahora, si cambio la imagen y hago que se adapte al 100% del ancho, las áreas del mapa fallan:

```html
<map name="mapa">
  <area shape="circle" coords="125,125,50" href="javascript:alert('Círculo')" />
  <area shape="rectangle" coords="325,75,425,175" href="javascript:alert('Cuadrado')" />
</map>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvHyu.png" usemap="#mapa" style="width:100%" />
```

¿Cómo se puede hacer para que las áreas del mapa se adapten como la imagen? ¿Hay alguna alternativa mejor que usar mapas (sin restricción alguna: se podría cambiar la estructura HTML, el CSS, añadir JavaScript, SVG...)?

Comment: El efecto es normal ya que las coordenadas del area estan en pixeles y por lo tanto se aplican unicamente a una imagen con tamaño sin deformación (aka sin forzar un nuevo tamaño como width=100%)

Comment: Por lo mismo , si usas un map, no podrás adaptarlo a algo responsivo. La alternativa es SVG por ejemplo, en el cual puedes incluso poner los onclick sobre cada uno de los elementos. He hecho muchos mapas de paises y del mundo de esta manera y funciona de maravilla con SVG, además de ser compatible con todos los browsers incluso los de mobile

Comment: @PhilippeThomassigny Deberías poner eso como respuesta. Al menos conseguirías un +1 por mi parte ;)

Comment: yo tuve que hacer un mapa de imagen responsivo. Era una funcionalidad que me pasaron ya hecha y tenía que hacerlo sí o sí con un mapa de imagen. Lo mejor que encontré fue un plugin de jquery que funciona bastante bien, es este: https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps

Comment: @blonfu esa Es una alternativa. Po lo como respuesta con un ejemplo si Es posible

Comment: Ya lo ha hecho Hoose. El plugin lleva años sin actualizar pero funciona, también he encontrado este otro más reciente y que da la opción de usarlo sin jQuery: https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/image-map-resizer, en el ejemplo que ponen parece que funciona bien, podría ser otra opción a valorar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Complementando la respuesta de Philippe, podrías hacer uso de algún plugin como
[jQuery RWD Image Maps](https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps), el cual permite recalcular las coordenadas del area del map y poder adaptarse al tamaño de la ventana.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0082)http://mattstow.com/experiment/responsive-image-maps/rwd-image-maps.html#buttercup -->
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <title>Responsive Image Maps jQuery Plugin</title>
 <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
 <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, target-densitydpi=160dpi, initial-scale=1">
 <script src="./Responsive Image Maps jQuery Plugin_files/ios-orientationchange-fix.min.js"></script>
 <style>
 body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 }
 h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
 }
 div {
  width: 100%;
 }
 img[usemap] {
  border: none;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
 }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
 <h1>Responsive Image Maps jQuery Plugin</h1>
 <p>Allows image maps to be used in a responsive design by recalculating the area coordinates to match the actual image size on load and window.resize.</p>
 <p><a href="https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps">Download the plugin from github</a></p>
 <p>This image map was created in minutes with Adobe Fireworks.</p>
 <img src="http://mattstow.com/experiment/responsive-image-maps/powerpuff-girls.fw.jpg" width="1024" height="768" usemap="#powerpuffgirls" alt="">
 <map name="powerpuffgirls">
  <area shape="poly" coords="122,36,281,36,285,37,287,39,289,42,289,46,289,48,278,77,276,81,274,84,271,84,218,84,218,90,210,90,208,95,207,99,204,100,72,100,26,87,23,84,20,81,19,75,35,40,37,37,43,34,62,34,65,30,68,25,72,25,115,25,119,27,121,30,122,36,122,36" href="#" title="The Powerpuff Girls" alt="The Powerpuff Girls">
  <area shape="poly" coords="864,667,912,649,922,667,971,667,973,718,981,721,985,729,988,730,1010,730,1010,742,833,742,833,730,865,730,865,721,874,721,874,718,864,667,864,667" href="#" title="Cartoon Network" alt="Cartoon Network">
  <area shape="poly" coords="1010,297,995,281,979,267,962,255,944,248,927,242,909,237,876,236,857,237,838,240,817,246,797,255,778,266,761,281,746,299,735,321,730,335,728,345,726,348,721,348,709,344,711,360,718,378,708,380,697,388,688,397,685,403,685,411,686,418,691,424,698,429,707,430,735,426,743,427,752,433,762,444,774,454,798,469,787,483,779,481,772,481,761,486,753,495,747,505,746,516,746,520,748,526,751,532,759,538,741,561,734,571,732,583,733,591,737,598,744,604,754,607,765,604,776,597,797,570,817,543,857,487,865,487,893,487,910,484,924,483,930,483,935,484,939,490,934,496,931,501,929,505,932,514,938,519,945,522,954,523,966,520,979,516,985,511,989,507,993,499,994,493,991,484,986,475,967,463,982,454,998,439,1013,424,1024,409,1024,329,1017,312,1010,297,1010,297" href="#" title="Buttercup" alt="Buttercup">
  <area shape="poly" coords="571,100,563,83,562,66,549,80,541,96,537,112,536,127,537,141,531,141,508,141,508,141,511,133,517,126,533,114,500,111,476,111,452,114,438,118,424,124,410,130,400,139,392,151,390,166,391,174,394,183,400,190,409,198,391,215,379,234,371,252,368,270,367,276,368,297,371,315,381,338,396,357,414,375,399,378,387,385,379,393,377,405,378,412,382,418,388,424,395,429,411,433,425,435,431,445,439,456,459,474,480,487,502,499,514,507,523,514,528,523,530,534,529,541,526,547,515,562,532,556,548,547,562,535,574,523,583,508,590,490,594,469,596,448,596,430,591,409,587,397,599,390,613,381,628,371,643,356,657,336,666,312,669,299,670,284,669,276,668,264,670,263,697,263,704,261,711,257,716,251,719,243,718,236,715,231,706,221,694,215,683,213,677,213,670,215,664,219,656,231,645,215,652,206,657,198,660,190,662,181,660,169,655,157,648,150,638,142,617,130,596,120,582,112,571,100,571,100" href="#" title="Blossom" alt="Blossom">
  <area shape="poly" coords="254,285,232,270,207,260,179,254,150,252,119,254,103,257,88,263,71,270,61,275,58,273,57,273,45,269,36,267,17,270,7,276,1,282,0,282,0,285,0,290,0,351,2,354,1,354,1,390,3,400,5,409,9,420,22,441,39,460,58,475,47,480,38,487,32,493,30,504,33,514,41,523,53,531,69,534,77,532,85,529,90,525,93,517,91,511,88,508,85,505,85,502,86,499,89,496,97,496,120,499,138,502,154,502,167,502,185,531,215,576,235,609,241,616,248,622,255,625,265,628,273,625,280,621,285,613,287,604,283,592,276,580,261,558,269,553,273,547,276,541,277,535,274,523,267,513,257,504,250,501,244,501,240,502,237,502,225,487,242,478,259,468,276,451,282,447,292,445,318,450,327,448,334,445,339,439,341,430,337,418,329,409,318,400,307,397,301,397,301,393,301,391,303,391,321,393,336,391,352,387,370,380,387,369,373,368,364,363,358,360,353,354,350,347,347,330,345,312,343,302,340,293,336,285,331,279,318,272,305,267,293,266,282,267,272,270,262,276,254,285,254,285" href="#" title="Bubbles" alt="Bubbles">
        </map>
</div>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://mattstow.com/experiment/responsive-image-maps/jquery.rwdImageMaps.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
 $('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();
 
 $('area').on('click', function() {
  alert($(this).attr('alt') + ' clicked');
 });
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

El Snippet es sacado de [aquí](http://mattstow.com/experiment/responsive-image-maps/rwd-image-maps.html)

Answer (score 3):

Podrías simular el mapa de imagen con enlaces y css, no se si es lo que necesitas.
(puedes verlo también aquí https://jsfiddle.net/fvaldelvira/7ov6xmao/)

```css
img {
  width:100%;
}
div.container {
  position:relative;
}
div.aria-links {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
div.aria-links a {
  position:absolute;
  border:1px solid white;
}
div.aria-links a:hover {
  background:rgba(255,255,255,.3);
}
a.link-1 {
    top: 48.5%;
    left: 15.5%;
    width: 10.5%;
    height: 20.8%;
    border-radius: 46%/16% 17% 10% 8%;
}
a.link-2 {
    top: 47%;
    left: 51.4%;
    width: 10%;
    height: 21%;
    border-radius: 45% 36% 25% 15%/17% 17% 16% 10%;
    transform: skew(2deg, -1deg);
}
a.link-3 {
    top: 45%;
    right: 4.5%;
    width: 10%;
    height: 21%;
    border-radius: 48% 54% 19% 15%/19% 19% 11% 7%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="aria-links">
    <a href="#" class="link-1"></a>
    <a href="#" class="link-2"></a>
    <a href="#" class="link-3"></a>
  </div>
  <img src="http://67.media.tumblr.com/c3ca763f82308b9f0dceb603fd19c188/tumblr_n5ozv05dxO1qfirfao1_1280.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

El efecto es normal ya que las coordenadas del area estan en pixeles y por lo tanto se aplican únicamente a una imagen con tamaño sin deformación (aka sin forzar un nuevo tamaño como width=100%)

Por lo mismo , si usas un map, no podrás adaptarlo a algo responsivo. La alternativa es SVG por ejemplo, en el cual puedes incluso poner los onclick sobre cada uno de los elementos. He hecho muchos mapas de paises y del mundo de esta manera y funciona de maravilla con SVG, además de ser compatible con todos los browsers incluso los de mobile

Hay mucha literatura para SVG:

http://www.w3schools.com/svg/

https://www.w3.org/2002/Talks/www2002-svgtut-ih/hwtut.pdf

https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/

http://www.desarrolloweb.com/manuales/29/

y bueno solo con buscar SVG en youtube o google, encontrarás toda la literatura, manuales, formatos, tutoriales etc.

Saludos